# How to track user location when the app is killed using flutter?

Tags: flutter, geolocation, background-process

I want to create a project that tracks the user's location when the app is closed or the app is running and then sends user data to Firebase. I chose Flutter to create this project. I'm new in flutter. How to I develop this application? Help me with some advice or related guidelines so I can develop this application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Flutter google maps.
2. Enable google maps API in google cloud console for your platform(s), Android, iOS if you want web.
3. Install your location dependency.
4. Update your database with the new coords when they change.
5. Build your map widget on your 2nd party's device, as per the documentation, 7. which is crystal clear,and put it in a streambuilder.
6. Update this map with the new coords.

   You get a location tracking system.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion @AnandhKrishnan
I can fetch data when the app is running but I cannot fetch data when the app is closed. How can I fetch data when the app is closed?

Comment: try my another answer